# EE3 CP Overview page and removing the "ExpressionEngine News" block

Tags: control-panel, ee3, cpanel

How does one remove certain blocks from the CP overview page particularly the "ExpressionEngine News" block.

Answer (score 0):

it's in the member group settings:Show news on CP homepage

Comment: Thanks, but I can't find it. Super Admin is locked

Comment: yeah... you'll need to be a super admin to set that setting...

Comment: I am Super Admin and I can't edit setting for Super Admin. I suppose I can duplicate Super Admin and turn off news in the new group and then delete the original Super Admin.

Comment: Strange that the Super Admin group settings are lock even to the Super Admin

Comment: It's default behaviour. You can't change the settings for the SA group